# validation engine to perform any validation at runtime

Tags: oracle, validation, oracle-apex

Currently oracle apex is providing validation to create at any level with any operator ,
However my requirement is to define the validation at user level , like user should be able to set any validation criteria at any level on front end which will work same as oracle apex validation , expecting table structure with respect to validation definitions at user level or any other idea where we can use the same apex validation engine on front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's possibly a few ways you could tackle this, depending on the types of validations you want to perform, and how much flexibility you can provide the users.

There are functions made available within the [apex_plugin_util](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/GET_PLSQL_EXPRESSION_RESULT-Function.html#GUID-1BA415C4-8700-4995-B6F0-AF93F356E887) API that could help your cause. eg:

```
select apex_plugin_util.get_plsql_expression_result  ('1+2') sm
 ,apex_plugin_util.get_plsql_expression_result  (':app_id') bv
 ,apex_plugin_util.get_plsql_expression_result  (q'~case when 1=2 then 'T' else 'F' end~') cse 
from dual;

SM    BV    CSE  
----- ----- -----
3     105   F
```

Comment: I have tried the same , however i am getting error as below
`[Error] Execution (27: 1): ORA-20987: APEX - Internal Error - Contact your application administrator.
Details about this incident are available via debug id "4504869".
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_CODE_EXEC_PLSQL", line 203
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2654
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220200", line 758
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1074
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1522
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1603
`

Comment: What expression have you attempted. Does debug mode give you any further detail?